# Trouble accessing private members with friend function in c++ operator<< overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function

So I'm trying to overload the << operator. From all the sources I can see, the syntax is correct, but eclipse doesn't like it.

I'm getting a couple errors:
*Polynomial::PrivateStruct* Polynomial::head is private*

And:
*struct Polynomial::PrivateStruct is private.*

I want to keep this struct private as to hide implementation details.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputStream, Polynomial& rhs)
    {
        Polynomial::PrivateStruct *p = rhs.head;
        //implementation details
        return outputStream;

    }
```

and the declaration:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputStream, const Polynomial& rhs);
```

Answer (score 6):

The declaration and the definition don't match - one takes a reference to `const`, the other to non-const. Match them and you're good to go.

Comment: Ah I can't believe I didn't spot that. Fresh eyes. Thanks!